# Error: NoSuchElementException when trying to read values from file to array

Tags: java, arrays, io, nosuchelementexception

Okay. So this is the last HW assignment of the semester, I am leaving out a big part of the program because this is the only thing I can't seem to fix. I am setting up my FileInputStream and using a for loop to read values into the array as I have done in the past without problems. For some reason I am getting this exception and can't figure it out. I have looked at plenty of other threads around this exception but likewise, cant seem to figure it out. Please halp.

Here is the code, it compiles;

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CollinDunn_1_10 {

  // Declare constants
  static final int MAX_EMPLOY = 30;
  static final String TAB = "\t";
  static final String NL = "\n";
  static final double IRA_INVEST = .08;
  static final double FEDERAL_WITH = .18;
  static final double STATE_WITH = .045;
  static final double SAVINGS = .10;

public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {

  // I/O String references
  final String INPUT = "CollinDunn_1_10_Input.txt";
  final String OUTPUT = "CollinDunn_1_10_Output.txt";

  // Declare variables
  // One-dimensional array for storing employee names
  String [] names = new String [MAX_EMPLOY];

  // Two-dimensional array for storing employee pay data
  // [0] hours worked [1] pay rate [2] gross pay [3] net pay
  // [4] savings amount [5] IRA amount [6] taxs withheld 
  double [][] payInfo = new double [MAX_EMPLOY][6];

  // Set up I/O
  FileInputStream inputDataFile = new FileInputStream(INPUT);
  Scanner inputFile  = new Scanner(inputDataFile);    
  FileWriter outputDataFile = new FileWriter(OUTPUT);
  PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(outputDataFile);

  // Read data from the file
  readData(inputFile, payInfo, names);

  // Test printing to see if values are stored - REMOVE 
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_EMPLOY; i++) {
     System.out.print(names[i] + TAB + payInfo[i][0] + TAB + payInfo[i][1]);
  }

} // End main

 // Method for reading file data into the file.
 // Data is sorted as (number of hours) (pay rate) (name)
 public static void readData (Scanner inputFile, double [][] payInfo, String [] names) {
     for (int i = 0; i < MAX_EMPLOY; i++) {
        payInfo [i][0] = inputFile.nextDouble();
        payInfo [i][1] = inputFile.nextDouble();
        names [i] = inputFile.nextLine();
     } // End For
  return;
} // End readData
} // End Class
```

*The fields on the text file are as so:
(hours) (pay) (name)

50.00  10.60 Light Karen L
52.00  10.80    Fagan Bert Todd
62.00  12.24  Antrim Forrest N*

```
The Exception and stack trace:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)

at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)

at CollinDunn_1_10.readData(CollinDunn_1_10.java:56)

at CollinDunn_1_10.main(CollinDunn_1_10.java:42)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never checking whether there is a value to retrieve before trying to retrieve it (look up Scanner.hasNextDouble). Since your for-loop goes through MAX_EMPLOY iterations, this exception will occur whenever your input file contains less than MAX_EMPLOY lines of data.

Answer (score 0):

You should everytime check if your tables or your file contains right amounts of elements or if they are big enought. Code should look like:

```
public static void readData (Scanner inputFile, double [][] payInfo, String [] names) {
     Integer payInfoLenght = payInfo.lenght;
     Integer namesLenght = names.lenght;
     if (MAX_EMPLOY > payInfoLenght || MAX_EMPLOY > namesLenght) {
          System.out.println("Wrong size of tabels");
     } else {
          for (int i = 0; i < MAX_EMPLOY; i++) {
             if (inputFile.hasNextDouble()) {
                 payInfo [i][0] = inputFile.nextDouble();
             }
             if (inputFile.hasNextDouble()) {
                 payInfo [i][1] = inputFile.nextDouble();
             }
             if (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
                 names [i] = inputFile.nextLine();
             }
          } 
     }
}
```

And you don't need "return;" at the end of this method becouse this method nothing returns. It's "void" method.

Comment: I get the bottom part and using hasNext on each assignment, but I don't get why you use if (MAX_EMPLOY > payInfoLength || MAX_EMPLOY > namesLength) this will always resort to true. Seeing as names and payInfo are partially filled to 25 when all fields are entered properly, MAX_EMPLOY will always be greater than the partially filled arrays.

Comment: You have non mutable tables. They have constant sizes. So it's better to check it. It is important how big is table not how much is filled.

If you are working with other persons you can't say that you have 100% certainty about something. It's fine to always check table sizes before working on them. In this method i don't know what is size of this tables, so i just check it to don't create another error.